# Selecting data with Symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, borehole

I have data along drill holes representing three elements (grades) as a function of thickness. One attribute. What I want is a way to select all the data of one element (i.e. 0.45% Cu / 1.00m, 2.10% Cu / 0.50m...) from all the drill holes to have only one color for each of the three elements.
In Symbology --> Categorized I have three colors: x.xx% Cu / m brown x.xx% Zn / m magenta x.xx% Cu - x.xx% Zn / m red thse value came from attribute Mx / m (one colomn) when I tried to select all Cu grades, I got nothing but the same color already displayed for all values.
In fact, I have to select each grade and choose the color manually, which takes a long time to process a more hundred data!

QGIS 3.34.3
MacOS 14.3 Sonoma

Comment: Can you be more specific, maybe add a screenshot of the Categorized form? I understand you have only three categories, so why do you mention "...a more hundred data!"? If you have several categories and you want to assign only three colors to those multiple categories, have you tried to use "Rule-based"  Symbology?

Answer (score 1):

You can try **rule based symbology**:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification

and use **operators** to build your query:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#operators

or more advanced **regular expression**.
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches

As example you can use ("sample" ist the field with your attributes (*0.45% Cu / 1.00m*)

```
 "sample"  ILIKE '%Zn%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found with the help of ChatGPT.
On Symbology ---> Rule based:
One rule per elemnt and we need toselect each color

"Mx / m" LIKE '% Cu%'

"Mx / m" LIKE '% Zn%'

"Mx / m" LIKE '% Cu% - % Zn%'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).